# Google map sometimes not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, cordova

I am currently working on a phonegap application where I followed the single page architecture. I have an index page `index.html` and all others pages are added as templates.

I have multiple tabs where in one of them I am displaying a Google map; it works fine but after navigating to different pages, sometimes when I come back to this map page, it is no longer displaying the map. When this happens it'll never start showing it again either, I need to explicitly restart the app.

I have loaded the map API on `index.html`, it is available throughout the application as it was loaded on the master page.
To load Google API I have used following link:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initMap
```

And to define map I have a global variable `map`, defined as:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMapCanvas"), myMapOption);
```

But for a while it loads the map, and then stops loading anything.

I tested this in various ways:

- By removing other map event listeners
- By adding height/width on map div (as an inline style); I at first defined it via external css
- By defining the dimension of the map's parent div.
- Encapsulated the block with try/catch even though it was not throwing an exception.

Comment: have you tried google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); ? and to declare map as global variable remove the var.. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059034/how-to-use-google-maps-event-triggermap-resize

Comment: resize event also not get called.