# Google Map not Loading after jquery show() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

My problem is that google map is not loading after show() function calls in jquery. I'm using display:none for closing division on page load. SO i figure out that it's done through google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') but i don't know **where to place google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') it in my jquery**. Bootstrap model pop up properly showing map and address and other functionalities are working fine. But after click on show function of jquery it's not loading properly.

I have read these questions on SO : 1). ([Google Maps Display:None Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700594/google-maps-displaynone-problem))
2) ([How to use google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059034/how-to-use-google-maps-event-triggermap-resize))

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBNEQCHUYPsekbYz7tym8Q4Ne2vlUsvnFc"></script>
            <!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script> -->
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".address_open").click(function(){ 
                    // i don't know the placing of this function. 
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                    $(".Mymap1").show();
            });
            });
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                var map;
                var marker;
                var coords = new google.maps.LatLng();
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.022505,72.5713621);
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                function initialize(){
                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 18,
                        center: myLatlng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), mapOptions);
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: myLatlng,
                        draggable: true 
                    });     

                    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': myLatlng }, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (results[0]) {
                                $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                                $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                                $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                                infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        }
                    });


                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {

                    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (results[0]) {
                                $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                                $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                                $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
                                infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
                }
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            </script>
```

Bootstrap Model

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                              <h4 class="modal-title">Map View</h4>
                            </div>                          
                            <div class="modal-body">
                              <div id="myMap" class="Mymap1"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Other division for click on map.

```
     <div class="form-group">
                              <label> Address</label>
                              <input type="text" id="address" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="txtName" value="<?php if(isset($fname)){echo $fname;} else { echo ""; }  ?>"  class="form-control abc address_open" />     
                                 <input type="hidden" id="latitude" placeholder="Latitude"/>
                                 <input type="hidden" id="longitude" placeholder="Longitude"/>                   
 </div>
```

Comment: <div id="myMap" class="Mymap1"></div> set width:100% and height:100%, have you tried this?

Comment: yeah brother  i tried with both  1)  width:100%;float:left;  2) width:100%;height:100%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below code to

```
        $(".address_open").click(function(){ 
                // i don't know the placing of this function. 
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                $(".Mymap1").show();
        });
```

This

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
  $(".Mymap1").show();//Am not sure what is this?
});
```

Cause you are already have data-target on button that is pointing to the modal. Inside 'show.bs.modal' event you can do more works, this fires on modal open

Comment: Yeh great... it's working like a charm.. Thank you brother...!