# Javascript: Google maps set marker latitude longitude every x seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to learn how to move a marker on the google map every x seconds (without refreshing the map or page ofcourse).

I have come across quite a few code and tutorials and questions on STO about moving or updating markers but they all want to do it via AJAX.

I don't want to do it via AJAX.

Basically, the `lat/long` of the marker gets stored in the `localstorage();`

So to move the marker every x seconds, I just need to look inside the localstorage as opposed to call AJAX etc etc...

The local storage looks something like this:

```
var lat = localStorage.getItem("mylat");
var lng = localStorage.getItem("mylng");
```

and the values of them are just simple string like so:

```
51.54647477
0.123383777
```

So, if I change any of those values locally (NO AJAX), I need teh marker to move or update its location so to speak.

First, is this even possible?

MAYBE, USING `SETINTERVAL()` ?!

If so, could someone please advise on this or point me in the right direction?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I think I'm getting somewhere. the issue is that the marker gets removed:

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wduno9su/4/)

If I use the lat/long values directly in the code the marker doesn't disappear in it moves but when I use the input value or localstorage valu, the marker disappears.

**Works:**

```
var NewLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(20.371237, 72.90634);
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
var NewLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(input);
```

**Another EDIT:**

This works now but it only moves the marker once and it wont move it again if I edit the inputs values:

http://jsfiddle.net/wduno9su/5/

**This works fine now:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {





    var map;


         function initialize()
         {


           var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.16536,72.79387);



           var myOptions = {
               zoom: 5,
               center: latlng,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };


           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker
           (
               {
                   position: new google.maps.LatLng(21.1673643, 72.7851802),
                   map: map,
                   title: 'Click me'
               }

           );




           var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: 'Location info:<br/>SVNIT Post Office, Dumas Rd, Surat<br/>LatLng:<br/>21.1673643, 72.7851802'
           });
           google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function ()
           {
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
              setTimeout(function(){infowindow.close();}, '5000');
           });

       //$('#clickme').on('click', function(){
       setInterval(function() {
           var input = $('#input').val();
           var input2 = $('#input2').val();


            var NewLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(input, input2);
            //setInterval(function() { marker.setPosition(NewLatLng);}, 2000);
            marker.setPosition( NewLatLng );
    });   


       }





       window.onload = initialize;



    });
```

Comment: You have to trigger the google map again and again

[check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059034/how-to-use-google-maps-event-triggermap-resize)

Comment: @Dherya, what am I suppose to check there?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you have tried that didn't work.

Comment: @geocodezip, please view the edit in my question. I've added a fiddle.. I only wish you would stop downvoting my questions though lol...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `setInterval` to periodically read the `localStorage` and set the marker position (creating the marker if it doesn't exist).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/khtLq2de/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var marker;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
}

function setLocalStorage() {
  var lat = document.getElementById('lat').value;
  var lng = document.getElementById('lng').value;
  localStorage.setItem('mylat', lat);
  localStorage.setItem('mylng', lng);
}
setInterval(function() {
  var lat = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("mylat"));
  var lng = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("mylng"));
  map.panTo({
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng
  });
  if (!marker || !marker.setPosition) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      },
      map: map
    });
  } else {
    marker.setPosition({
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
    });
  }
}, 5000);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="lat" value="42" />
<input id="lng" value="-72" />
<input type="button" onclick="setLocalStorage();" value="click" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```