# Is there an update for google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");?

Tags: cordova, resize, maps

I'm working on a google maps cordova app and the map  is not loading fully. I have been advised to use google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); but I have learned that the resize event is no longer part of the map class. What can I use as an alternative to google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); to fully load the map?

Comment: Refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059034/how-to-use-google-maps-event-triggermap-resize

Comment: I have seen that before, it's the reason why I asked this question. The link which is provided there and supposed to have the documentation is empty.