# 'google' is not defined Using Google Maps JavaScript API Loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps

I have a Vue CLI project that uses the Google Maps JavaScript API Loader. I import the loader using the code below:

```
import { Loader } from "@googlemaps/js-api-loader";
```

After that, I defined the loader, like so:

```
const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: "XXXXX",
  version: "weekly",
  libraries: ["places"]
});
```

Now, when I try to display a map using the google.maps.Map object, I get an error stating that 'google' is not defined. All the code above is in the project's 'main.js' file in the 'src' directory and the code below is the last bit that, unfortunately, triggers the error.

```
loader.load().then(() => {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I installed *@googlemaps/js-api-loader* using npm, as per instructions from the Google documentation.

Comment: Hi @Goodman L I got the same problem as you. You was solve it?

Comment: Please comment on this issue if you would like the promise to resolve to window.google or window.google.maps. https://github.com/googlemaps/js-api-loader/issues/224

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi @Goodman L you have to try it. Just add `window` at the front of your code.. happy coding

```
window.google.maps.Map
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I am only getting back to you now. I have tried your solutions and it does not give errors. However, there is no map showing. I have double-checked the coordinates and API keys and everything is in order.

Comment: I think you should read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation)

Comment: That is where I started. I can see that something is being done to the element I provided in the promise but no map is being displayed. I will keep checking. Thank you.

Comment: I wasn't seeing the map after making the changes you suggested because my container did not have a height attribute. Now it does and the map is displaying. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

The new package does not return a 'google' object when the promise is resolved, instead it is attached to the `window`. To use it as you would if following the Vue tutorial (that I am also following) you would need to add:

`this.google = window.google`

To the map component. For clarity:

```
async mounted() {
   // As per the documentation for the google maps API loader
   const googleMapApi = await Loader({
       apiKey: this.apiKey
    })

    // This returns a promise, but not a 'google' object
    this.google = await googleMapApi.load();
    // Set the google object from the correct location
    this.google = window.google;
    this.initializeMap();
},

methods: {
    initializeMap() {
        const mapContainer = this.$refs.googleMap;
        this.map = new this.google.maps.Map(mapContainer, this.mapConfig);
    }
}
```

The reference to the tutorial I talk about: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/practical-use-of-scoped-slots.html

Comment: Please comment on this issue if you would like the promise to resolve to window.google or window.google.maps. github.com/googlemaps/js-api-loader/issues/224

Comment: this sorted things out for me

Comment: I followed the same example had to change 'await googleMapApi' in new 'googleMapApi'

Answer (score 1):

Let’s first establish our `GoogleMapLoader.vue` template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="google-map" ref="googleMap"></div>
    <template v-if="Boolean(this.google) && Boolean(this.map)">
      <slot
        :google="google"
        :map="map"
      />
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

Now, our script needs to pass some props to the component which allows us to set the Google Maps API and Map object:

```
import GoogleMapsApiLoader from 'google-maps-api-loader'

export default {
  props: {
    mapConfig: Object,
    apiKey: String,
  },

  data() {
    return {
      google: null,
      map: null
    }
  },

  async mounted() {
    const googleMapApi = await GoogleMapsApiLoader({
      apiKey: this.apiKey
    })
    this.google = googleMapApi
    this.initializeMap()
  },

  methods: {
    initializeMap() {
      const mapContainer = this.$refs.googleMap
      this.map = new this.google.maps.Map(
        mapContainer, this.mapConfig
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Please follow this tutorial for the correct way to do it.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/practical-use-of-scoped-slots.html

Comment: I see you have used a different package from the one I am using. Let me try it then revert.

Comment: So, google-maps-api-loader has been deprecated and @googlemaps/js-api-loader is suggested instead. That's what I am using and facing issues with.

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-api-loader